# How to show multiple time reload dialog box with customize question using react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

asking custom question

```
function handlePageReload(event:any) {
            const message = 'Are you sure you want to reload the page?';
            event.returnValue = message;
            return message;
          }
          useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handlePageReload);
          
            return () => {
              window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handlePageReload);
            };
          }, []);
```

I need show reload dialog box every refresh on the browser. how?